# Limiting prop-passing into React components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a scenario where I have two components that both use a `TagInput` component I've written. Unfortunately, there are a lot of callbacks that the `TagInput` needs, for tag adding, creation, removal, etc. So the code looks something like this:

```
<ComponentOne
  onTagAdd={this.tagAdd}
  onTagCreate={this.tagCreate}
  onTagDelete={this.tagDelete}
  onTagSetAll={this.tagSetAll}
/>

<ComponentTwo
  onTagAdd={this.tagAdd}
  onTagCreate={this.tagCreate}
  onTagDelete={this.tagDelete}
  onTagSetAll={this.tagSetAll}
/>
```

On top of any other props these two components need, that could amount to quite a long list.

My question is, is there a much better way to structure this? The only workaround I can think of is to have a single callback, like so:

```
<ComponentOne
  onTagAction={this.handleTagAction}
/>

<ComponentTwo
  onTagAction={this.handleTagAction}
/>
```

And then an action and arguments are passed to the callback:

```
handleTagAction = (action, args) => {
  switch (action) {
    case 'add':
      break;
    case 'create':
      break;
    // ...
  }
};
```

Is there a better way I'm not thinking of?

Comment: In which context these elements should be used? I mean are they doing the same job, or they belong to the different contexts. So generally any information about bigger picture would be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also have a single object, something like

```
const tagActions = {
   add : this.tagAdd,
   create : this.tagCreate,
   delete : this.tagDelete,
   setAll : this.tagSetAll, 
}
```

and then pass `tagActions` as a single prop to your components. From your component, you could then call the method based on the use-case, for example `this.props.tagActions.add()`